# using Dropbox on my homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am building a Dropbox API JavaScript App. At the moment, users can login with their Dropbox Account, which is done by a jQuery Library that also creates a Folder in the users Dropbox which can be used by the App.
Now I want the user to manage the files of this dropbox folder on my homepage. The best way, in my opinion, was to make an iframe, but that does not work with Dropbox. Now I am struggling with the Dropbox Datastore API, but I don't get functions to work.

```
Dropbox.Client.prototype.readdir("test", {removed:false},
function(a,b,c,d){
  alert("hello");
});
```

This, for example, returns the Error "this.urls is undefined".

[Dropbox Documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/js)

I guess I am doing something fundamental wrong, but I couldn't find any tutorial on this.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: As a side note, the Datastore API is for working with structured data, not files. The part of the Dropbox API you're using is called the Core API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `readdir` directly from a class's prototype instead of an instance of that class. You may want to read up on object-oriented programming in JavaScript.

Presumably somewhere, since you're logging in a user, you have a `Dropbox.Client` *object*, and you should be calling methods on that object. E.g.

```
var client = new Dropbox.Client({ key: '...' });
// ...
client.readdir("test", { removed: false }, function (err, ...) { ... });
```

Comment: Thank you. This also helped me: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/71/writing-a-file-with-the-dropbox-javascript-sdk